# Which one is faster method to count number of 1's?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, time-complexity

Suppose I want to count the number of 1's in a binary number n in Python
then I can do this using the following two methods.

```
def count_ones(n):
    count=0
    while n>0:
        count+=n&1
        n=n>>1
    return count
```

or I can first convert the given number into binary and then count 1 like

```
bin(n).count('1')
```

Which way is better(with respect to Time complexity) and why?

Comment: It is obvious that the second method is faster than the first one but I don't understand why? Is it because of predefined library functions work faster than user-defined or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of the first function is O(log n), because that's how many bits it takes to represent n in binary, and both `bin(n)` and `.count('1')` take linear time in the number of bits.

The time complexity of the second function is O(log<sup>2</sup> n), because the loop iterates O(log n) times and the bit shift `n >> 1` inside the loop takes O(log n) time. That is, the number of iterations is linear in the number of bits, and the shift takes linear time in the number of bits.

So, the time complexity of the first function is lower.